# Web Application Crash/Hangs on IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11, mshtml

My web application is running fine on both Firefox and Chrome.

But while trying to run on IE11 (In Windows 10), web application randomly get Crashed with follow error

> The assembly instruction at
>   mshtml!Tree::TableCellBlock::EnsureTableStructureRelatedFormatsAreReadyToUse+5
>   in C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll from Microsoft Corporation has
>   caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read
>   from memory location 0x00000008 on thread 39
>
> Full Call Stack
>
> Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
>   mshtml!Tree::TableCellBlock::EnsureTableStructureRelatedFormatsAreReadyToUse+5
>   6cf07460     112d9470     187a2ee0     00000000
>   mshtml!Layout::TableGridBox::HandleChildDisplayChangesAndAggregateBounds_Const+b9
>   1282fe28     06aad5bc     42c80000     112d9534
>   mshtml!Layout::LayoutBox::HandleDisplayChange_Const+101e     00000000 
>   1282fe28     06aad5bc     42c80000
>   mshtml!Layout::LayoutBox::HandleChildDisplayChangesAndAggregateBounds+c9
>   1282fe28     06aad5bc     42c80000     112d9754
>   mshtml!Layout::TableBox::HandleChildDisplayChangesAndAggregateBounds_Const+41
>   1282fe28     06aad5bc     42c80000     112d9754
>   mshtml!Layout::LayoutBox::HandleDisplayChange_Const+101e     00000000 
>   1282fe28     06aad5bc     42c80000
>   mshtml!Layout::FlowBoxBuilder::ReuseChildBox+5f6     187f8460
>   112d9bfc     112d9bfc     00000000
>   mshtml!Layout::FlowBoxBuilder::AttemptToReuseChildBox+15c     1a0978cc
>   112d9bfc     112d99c8     1282fe00
>   mshtml!Layout::FlowBoxBuilder::BuildBoxItem+30a     112d9bfc
>   112d9bfc     112d9bbc     00000000

and other random crash errors

> The assembly instruction at ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+10e in
>   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an
>   unknown exception (0xc0000008) on thread 28

or

> The assembly instruction at jscript9!IsNativeFunctionAddr+3 in
>   C:\Windows\System32\jscript9.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused
>   an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from
>   memory location 0x000004b4 on thread 21

Not sure how to debug this; any help will be appreciated.